# Talend ESB : How to validate XML request against a XSD file

Tags: talend

I am using Talend Open Studio 5.4.

I have created a service, which on finish generates all schema required for the same service. I have assigned a new job for the service and trying validate input XML request against the request XSD file.

I followed [this link](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide53EN/tXSDValidator), it worked fine, but when I tried to validate an input XML request, as `tESBProviderRequst` will receive, it did not work.

[image]

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Talend expert, but the way i do this is by transforming first my payload (which type is a "document") into a string, so that the tXSDValidator could work.

[image]

The second conversion is just here to allow me to build a custom response with my input fields.
But in any cases, i think you have to pass a document object to your tESBProviderResponse.

I hope it helps.